# Why it says 'push_back' has not been declared?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Why it says 'push_back' has not been declared ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  vector <int> v(30);
  v[0].push_back(0);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the complete, exact error message, including any line numbers it refers to.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`v[0]` is a reference to the initial element in the `vector`; it isn't the `vector` itself.  The element is of type `int`, which is not a class type object and therefore has no member functions.

Are you looking for `v.push_back(0);`?

Note that `vector<int> v(30);` creates the `vector` with 30 elements in it, each with a value of zero.  Calling `v.push_back(0);` will increase the size of the `vector` to 31.  This may or may not be the behavior your want; if it isn't, you'll need to clarify what, exactly, you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `v.push_back(0)` as `push_back` is the method of the vector not its element.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  vector <int> v(30);
  v.push_back(0);
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that v[0] is the first element in vector, which is an int. The name of the vector is v.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `v.push_back(0);` You have to push_back into a vector. Not into a specific element of a vector.

Answer (score 2):

use `v.push_back(0)` as `v[0]` is an `int` and not a `vector`.

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong type.

`v` is of type **Vector**.   `v[0]` is **NOT** a vector, rather, it is a reference to the first element (which will be an `int`).

As a result, `v[0]` does not have a `push_back` method.
Only the vector itself (`v`) has the method.